# react-native-chart-wrapper <BarChart> Zoom out issue after pinch to zoom

Tags: react-native, bar-chart, mobile-application, react-native-charts-wrapper

After Pinch to zoom, I am unable to reset zoom while replacing new data

```
import { BarChart } from 'react-native-charts-wrapper'; 
 <BarChart                                
                style={styles.grpBarChartStyle}
                                    xAxis={this.state.grpBarChartxAxis}
                                    data={this.state.grpBarChartdata}
                                    legend={this.state.grpBarChartlegend}
                                    drawValueAboveBar={false}
                                    onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
                                    highlights={this.state.highlights}
                                    marker={this.state.marker}
                                    chartDescription={{
                                        text: ''
                                    }}
                                />
```

I tries for xAxis and yAxis but that is change the size of whole chart, and I want to zoom out the inner chart

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting *pinchZoom={false}*

```
<BarChart
  pinchZoom={false}
  style={styles.grpBarChartStyle}
  xAxis={this.state.grpBarChartxAxis}
  data={this.state.grpBarChartdata}
  legend={this.state.grpBarChartlegend}
  drawValueAboveBar={false}
  onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
  highlights={this.state.highlights}
  marker={this.state.marker}
  chartDescription={{
    text: "",
  }}
/>;
```